# Storing data in the blockchain inside a transaction

Tags: storage, pyethereum, pyethapp, calldata

This question is related to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/what-are-some-proposed-ways-of-storing-data-in-ethereum) one and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block) one. I'm trying to store data in the blockchain inside the transaction data field:

The second question offers a solution using a contract but is it possible to use only the transaction field. In pyethapp it is defined as follows:

```
class Transaction(rlp.Serializable):

    """
    A transaction is stored as:
    [nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, v, r, s]

    nonce is the number of transactions already sent by that account, encoded
    in binary form (eg.  0 -> '', 7 -> '\x07', 1000 -> '\x03\xd8').

    (v,r,s) is the raw Electrum-style signature of the transaction without the
    signature made with the private key corresponding to the sending account,
    with 0 <= v <= 3. From an Electrum-style signature (65 bytes) it is
    possible to extract the public key, and thereby the address, directly.

    A valid transaction is one where:
    (i) the signature is well-formed (ie. 0 <= v <= 3, 0 <= r < P, 0 <= s < N,
        0 <= r < P - N if v >= 2), and
    (ii) the sending account has enough funds to pay the fee and the value.
    """

    fields = [
        ('nonce', big_endian_int),
        ('gasprice', big_endian_int),
        ('startgas', big_endian_int),
        ('to', utils.address),
        ('value', big_endian_int),
        ('data', binary),
        ('v', big_endian_int),
        ('r', big_endian_int),
        ('s', big_endian_int),
    ]

    _sender = None

    def __init__(self, nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, v=0, r=0, s=0):
        self.data = None

        to = utils.normalize_address(to, allow_blank=True)
        assert len(to) == 20 or len(to) == 0
        super(Transaction, self).__init__(nonce, gasprice, startgas, to, value, data, v, r, s)
        self.logs = []

        if self.gasprice >= TT256 or self.startgas >= TT256 or \
                self.value >= TT256 or self.nonce >= TT256:
            raise InvalidTransaction("Values way too high!")
        if self.startgas < self.intrinsic_gas_used:
            raise InvalidTransaction("Startgas too low")

        log.debug('deserialized tx', tx=encode_hex(self.hash)[:8])
```

I'm not sure whether the field has an upper bound in terms of size.

How much data can be stored within a transaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a limit for transaction size?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size)

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of `data` field is dependent on the block gas limit.

In the Ethereum public blockchain, the limit for the `data` field was **89kb** as of Feb 7, 2016. [Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size). You can use a similar methodology to check for the limit now.

However, In a private blockchain, there's no limit to the data field. You can set the block gas limit value in your genesis file. [Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/private-chain-maximum-size-of-data-field-in-an-ethereum-transaction)