# Can I use Ethereum to prove work?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, storage, proof-of-work, pyethereum

I need to store pdf hash in blockchain to prove my pdf existence. 
I thought to use blockchain, but public blockchain required some fee ...
I don't really understand if ethereum could be my solution...
Can I use ethereum for store hash for free ? And if ethereum can be use to prove work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store data in ethereum blockchain](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/how-can-i-store-data-in-ethereum-blockchain)

Comment: Agree with the duplicate, and the "prove work" question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the main net of Ethereum for [free](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions/frequently-asked-questions.html#id4). See [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/what-are-some-proposed-ways-of-storing-data-in-ethereum/1001#1001) answer for how you can use the Ethereum block chain in conjunction with a third party to store the hash of your .pdf.