# Error when including extra data in web3.eth.sendTransaction()

Tags: web3js, contract-development, metamask, sendtransaction

According to the docs for [`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) and the docs for [`eth_sendTransaction`](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Ethereum.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/eth_sendTransaction.html):

The transaction object can contain an optional `data` parameter which should be a `String` that consists of:

*either an ABI byte string containing the data of the function call on a contract, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction the initialisation code.*

I'd like to know the following:

1. Could I use `data` to store a `String` whose value would be anything I like? As in:

```
const [testAccount] = await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
    
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)

if (!testAccount) {
  return
}

await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: testAccount,
  to: testAccount,
  value:  web3.utils.toWei('0.0003'), 
  data: web3.utils.utf8ToHex(JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 }))
})
```

2. If the answer is yes, how big (in bytes) can this string be and if the gas fee increases according to the size of `data`, can I calculate that in advance ?

Thank you for your help

**UPDATE:** When I execute the code above, I get the following error:

```
Error:  Error: TxGasUtil - Trying to call a function on a non-contract address
{
  "originalError": {
    "errorKey": "transactionErrorNoContract",
    "getCodeResponse": "0x"
  }
}
```

Apparently, you cannot assign any string to `data` and expect the string to be incorporated in the record of the transaction on the blockchain, out-of-the-box, simply by assigning a value to it.

**Question:** Do I need to create a custom smart-contract in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a MetaMask issue.

See comment in [their code](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/14d85b133233d5f806480d8896f0c11cafc04a87/app/scripts/controllers/transactions/index.js#L348) -

> if there's data in the params, but there's no contract code, it's not a valid transaction

This issue was reported [here](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/3793).

FYI your code works perfectly on a non MetaMask env.

---

You can store a string, but encoded as a hex string. To store 'I love lamp' you need to set `data: '0x49206c6f7665206c616d70'`.

Use [utf8ToHex](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#utf8tohex) to convert a string to hex bytes -

```
web3.utils.utf8ToHex('I have 100€');
> "0x49206861766520313030e282ac"
```

To know how much gas it costs, use estimateGas, either on a [contract's method](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas), or [without](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#estimategas).

```
web3.eth.estimateGas({
    to: "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe",
    data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
})
.then(console.log);
```

Re transaction size -

> the transaction size limit, at the time of writing, is about 780kB (about 3 million gas).

info taken from this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/is-there-a-limit-for-transaction-size).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a size limit regarding `data` ? Or at least a maximum size below which I don't really need to worry about it ?

Comment: Added this to my answer. Feel free to accept the answer if this helps

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I get the error I mention in the updated OP. It looks like I need to create a custom contract ?

Comment: Updated my answer.