# Dealing with images on the blockchain

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am currently starting a project, mainly a Dapp on the ethereum blockchain. and i had a problem understanding how will i manage images and volumenous data  off the blockchain, while keeping the same security level given by ethereum.

If there is Any kinda of document or ressource i need to see, please tell.

Thanks

Comment: It is probably a duplicate. yet reviving old posts to add upon is not really the best thing.

Comment: Hi there. It's entirely the best thing, and considered best-practice on Stack Exchange. It prevents duplication of effort on the parts of people answering the questions, and provides a single, canonical place to look for an answer to a given question. New answers can be added to old questions, or previous answers can be edited. Also, that previous question is only 19 hours old... (And the question that it's duplicated to has a perfectly good answer.)

Answer (score 0):

As per my previous one of the post.

> Yes, you're right. Saving entire image in eth is very costly. I'll
>   suggest you to check off chain data storages like IPFS or Swarm
>   (Ethereum community usually recommends it).

Above mentioned two services are decentralised document store's. So I'll recommend to refer above mentioned data stores.

For more details please refer below links:

[How do you store image in the Ethereum Blockchain efficiently?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39279/how-do-you-store-image-in-the-ethereum-blockchain-efficiently/39282#39282)

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs#use-in-nodejs

http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/